# What's the difference between php_pdo_pgsql and php_pgsql PHP extensions?

Tags: php, postgresql, homebrew

My default php.ini file lists both extensions (installed via brew), and I sometimes see different variations on Linux (AMZN vs Centos) with the `_pdo_` bit. What is the difference?

Update: I was getting errors saying `pg_connect` not found and this seems to be part of the non-PDO version. To get this installed on Mac via brew, I needed to add support by running `brew reinstall php56 --with-postgresql`

Comment: It's like Coca-Cola vs Pepsi—just two alternatives for the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PDO is short for PHP Data Objects and is an abstraction that can be mapped on to a lot of different databases. This means you can move between things like MySQL, PGSQL and SQLite very easily. The PDO module enables the functions you see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for PGSQL.

The non-PDO module is specific to Postgres and will enable [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php) set of non-standardized functions that will only work with Postgres databases.

Answer (score 3):

The PDO extension can connect to different database management systems with the same syntax, as long as there's a driver for the system you want to use. The PostgreSQL extension can only connecto to PostgreSQL.

What you see is the PostgreSQL extension and the PDO driver for PostgreSQL.